# PyQt folder dialog change size after compiling

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, pyinstaller

Im using Python 2.7 and PyQt4. I wrote a simple program that ask for directory on exit using `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()`. Then it shows it in a `QMessageBox` and ask the user if he wants to quit. The full code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)        
        self.setWindowTitle('Message box')    
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            file, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()        


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works perfectlly as expected - The size is fine and it is resizable. However, when I compile the code using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), the folder dialog is full-screen and even can't be resized.

How can I prevent it from happening? Thanks

**Edit:**

To create the spec file, I use:

`C:\Python\Python279\Scripts\pyi-makespec --icon=icon.ico --noconsole --name="Test" Test.py`

To compile the code using the spec file, I use:

`C:\Python\Python279\Scripts\pyi-build Test.spec`

Comment: Mmh I don't know PyInstaller, but if you say you can run the programm as expected but not when you compile it with PyInstaller, then I think the issue is there.

Comment: Could you also present the script/commands for creating the installer with PyInstaller? Is the problem still existing?